# How to use elasticsearch for mutiple models in Django using the same search api

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-rest-framework

I am trying to implement an elastic search in Django for multiple models in a single search api. If I had to implement using different apis I can do in the following way.

my models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'


ARTICLE_TYPES = [
    ('UN', 'Unspecified'),
    ('TU', 'Tutorial'),
    ('RS', 'Research'),
    ('RW', 'Review'),
]


class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    author = models.ForeignKey(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=ARTICLE_TYPES, default='UN')
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(to=Category, blank=True, related_name='categories')
    content = models.TextField()
    created_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_datetime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.author}: {self.title} ({self.created_datetime.date()})'
```

my serializers.py

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = '__all__'

class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = UserSerializer()
    categories = CategorySerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
class CategoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
    queryset = Category.objects.all()


class ArticleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
```

documents.py

```
@registry.register_document
class CategoryDocument(Document):
    id = fields.IntegerField()

    class Index:
        name = 'categories'
        settings = {
            'number_of_shards': 1,
            'number_of_replicas': 0,
        }

    class Django:
        model = Category
        fields = [
            'name',
            'description',
        ]


@registry.register_document
class ArticleDocument(Document):
   
    categories = fields.ObjectField(properties={
        'id': fields.IntegerField(),
        'name': fields.TextField(),
        'description': fields.TextField(),
    })
    type = fields.TextField(attr='type_to_string')

    class Index:
        name = 'articles'
        settings = {
            'number_of_shards': 1,
            'number_of_replicas': 0,
        }

    class Django:
        model = Article
        fields = [
            'title',
            'content',
            'created_datetime',
            'updated_datetime',
        ]
```

My search views are:

```
class SearchCategories(PaginatedElasticSearchAPIView):
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
    document_class = CategoryDocument

    def generate_q_expression(self, query):
        return Q(
                'multi_match', query=query,
                fields=[
                    'name',
                    'description',
                ], fuzziness='auto')


class SearchArticles(PaginatedElasticSearchAPIView):
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
    document_class = ArticleDocument

    def generate_q_expression(self, query):
        return Q(
                'multi_match', query=query,
                fields=[
                    'title',
                    'author',
                    'type',
                    'content'
                ], fuzziness='auto')
```

My urls.py :

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('user/<str:query>/', SearchUsers.as_view()),
    path('category/<str:query>/', SearchCategories.as_view()),
    path('article/<str:query>/', SearchArticles.as_view()),
]
```

So, my issue is I have a search bar on the home page in the frontend in which a single api is to be called to search for all the models . I need to acheive search of multiple models with a single search api. But in above, different searalizers and views are created for different search query and are called from different url endpoints. How can we achieve it with a single api?

Comment: I think the answers in this link should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54347708/search-multiple-models-elasticsearch